# What is difference between perform_in and perform_async in sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I want to update old sidekiq jobs with new time interval. How I can do this ? Is it possible through `perform_in` option. In addition I want to know clear difference between `perform_in` and `perform_async`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have to pass `perform_in` a time. `perform_async` gets pushed to the queue right away. Other than that they're the same. You'd call `perform_in(10.minutes)`

Comment: Full documentation on the `perform_in` method is available at https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs

Comment: Is there documentation for perform, perform_now and perform_later? I think there are self explanatory but how would each be handled by Sidekiq?